# Notepad++/Eclipse sql code auto-indent option?

Tags: sql, eclipse, notepad++, code-formatting

DDL gets especially ugly. Is there any option of SQL auto-indenting for Notepad++? I've tried to do it in Eclipse, but the code doesn't react to auto-indent.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Yes, there is a free/open-source T-SQL formatting plugin for Notepad++, called "Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter". It is available in the NPP "Plugin Manager" plugin list (gets updated every once in a while automatically), and is also available for manually downloading/installing from here: http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx

If you just want to check it out without adding to notepad++, you can check the online formatting site:

http://poorsql.com

(disclaimer: I wrote these tools :))

Comment: I will check it! Cool dude, that will be very and very useful! I will even accept the answer half a year later :-D

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it's on the list of plugins that come with the plugin manager, and worked perfectly first time formatting to easily read SQL.

Comment: Notepad++ inclusion was very helpful.

Comment: Hi, this plugin doesn't seem to work in v5.9 of npp, does anyone having the same issue? It just crash as soon as I open npp.

Comment: no, this does not work and certainly does not appear in the npp list of possible plugins (am using notepad++ 6.8.8)

Comment: @adolfgarlic, HarryDuong, can you describe your issue in any more detail? there are known issues with the SSMS+VSS plugin on the latest versions of VS (Visual Studio) and SSMS (management studio), but no known issues with the Notepad++ plugin. When you navigate to "Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager", it should appear as "Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter" in the list, under P (in one of the tabs, depending on whether already installed).

Comment: The website is down... Does anyone know of any other site that has the zip file for notepad++?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh: the website is back up, sorry about that. Longer-term, the plan is to switch to a github-native way of delivering the plugin releases.

Comment: @Tao - Superb. Many thanks for that. And yes, the github way would be nice.

Comment: To run it once installed : `Plugins` | `Poor man's T-Sql formatter` | `Format T-SQL code`.

Answer (score 5):

There is also another free SQL Formatter plugin for Notepad++ with code folding and coloring and 100+ formatting option here: [SQLinForm Free Notepad++ Plug-n](http://sqlinform.com/sql-formatter-download-NotepadPlusPlus-Plugin.html). A free version is also available.

[image]