# How do I pretty format my SQL query in DBeaver?

Tags: sql, notepad++, sublimetext3, sublimetext, dbeaver

I use DBeaver for my main IDE to query multiple databases. When I query a table, it automatically generates a long select statement with all columns in one line.

When I am making more complex queries, this gets very cumbersome to work with and read. I would like to view the select values on separate lines rather than one long string.

Is there an easy way (perhaps by using Notepad++ or Sublime Text) to break up the query (with line breaks after the commas)?

For example,

```
select name, address, city, state, country, zip_code, birthday, membership_type 
from customers
```

to

```
select
name,
address,
city,
state,
country,
zip_code,
birthday,
membership_type
from customers
```

Comment: Google "sql tidy" and you'll find a number of results that do what you want. Try http://www.sql-format.com/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7871054/1015495

Answer (score 35):

DBeaver has a shortcut for this purpose. In SQL Editor:
[image]

Comment: To add here in case anyone else is struggling with this, I noticed that formatting of multiple sql statements doesn't work as expected if they don't have a semicolon after each of them. Once semicolons are added, it works great, as of version: 6.1.2.201907061627

Comment: Best answer because it's not using any other tool apart from DBeaver

Answer (score 13):

Yes there is.  I use Notepad++ because it is free and I use it for everything!  Anyways, Notepad++ has a Plugin called:  Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter.  It works with a click of a button.  You also get a few custom options like if you want to auto capitalize table names, etc.

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering how to use this with DBeaver. I picked the external formatter option and put `"C:\Users\user\Downloads\SqlFormatter.1.6.10\SqlFormatter.exe" ${file}` in the command line. I'm using a temp file. I set the timeout to 10 seconds. It doesn't error, but it doesn't format either.

Comment: Here's a link to the GitHub page where I asked this too. https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/285

Answer (score 12):

Select a query to be formatted and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> does the work.
I am using DBeaver 6.3.0

Answer (score 8):

There is another external SQL for DBeaver. It can be found here: [SQLinForm SQL Formatter](https://www.sqlinform.com/free-dbeaver-sql-formatter/) and can be included as external Formatter like this
[image: External Formatter for DBeaver]

Comment: The link is 404.

Answer (score 3):

In SublimeText I assume you have already installed [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io)? If not do so as soon as you can, it is a vital tool.

From Package Control there are a number of options to do what you want to do. [Here are some options](https://packagecontrol.io/search/sql)

I would start with [SqlBeautifier](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SqlBeautifier) and then try others to find which one suits your taste best.

Answer (score 0):

Write click on the screen, this menu will be pop-up, and follow the instructions shown in the attached image.
[image]

Comment: Can you describe how is your answer improving the answer from Yurii?

Answer (score -3):

use backtick ` instead of quote " or '

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: in my sublime, if i have a long query statement and i want to break it, i use backtick. for example:  var sql="select table1_id, table1_name from table1 where table1_id=? and table1_status=1" ; it will take one line only but using backtic ` i can break it into multiple lines for convenience purpose.